# Is there a way to simulate a doorlock device using a usb zigbee?

Tags: zigbee

I need to simulate a doorlock device(zigbee home automation standard) using a USB ZigBee dongle.
So when I'll open my zigbee network the USB will be visible as DoorLock system

Comment: Most ZigBee development kits will have sample code in their stack to simulate various Home Automation (HA) devices.  What platform are you using?  Freescale?  Silicon Labs?  Other?  If they support the HA profile, it should be easy to simulate the DoorLock.

Comment: @tomlogic The module that I have is made from Difi and ia: XBee pro s1

Comment: I don't believe the Digi XBee modules support the Home Automation profile yet, and you'd need to use a Series 2 module.  Note that "XBee" is not the same thing as "ZigBee".

Comment: @tomlogic you know some module that are able to simulate doorlock system?